# Is there any clean way to create samba share for multiple homes?

Tags: linux, samba

I'm using [homes] section for every user for their /home/username directory. The code in smb.conf is like this

```
[homes]
   comment = Home Directories
   browseable = no
   read only = no
   create mask = 0664
   directory mask = 2775
   valid users = %S
```

But I also have a 2nd disk and I want to create /home2/username for everyone on it. Now I add one path for every user like this and it is so tedious.

```
[jack2]
    browseable = no
    path = /home2/jack
    read only = no
    create mask = 0664
    directory mask = 2775
    valid users = jack

 [fiona2]
    browseable = no
    path = /home2/fiona
    read only = no
    create mask = 0664
    directory mask = 2775
    valid users = fiona
...
```

I wish there is something like (this doesn't work)

```
[%S2]
    browseable = no
    path = /home2/%S
    read only = no
    create mask = 0664
    directory mask = 2775
    valid users = %S
```

so I don't need to add each one for them (the share name has a '2' appended to its name to distinguish it from the normal homes). It it possible?

I'm administrator of our private server. I also use lvm on it but since I'm new to lvm and for reliability reason I didn't merge all disks into a whole one so each disk has its home directory.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I take it that you are manually creating the users directories (Samba doesn't do this automatically)
You could use the 'root preexec' parameter in your [homes] share to run a script to create the directories when the user connects, you could also create a new share called something like '[users]' and do something similar.

Comment: I'm manually creating the directories but it's ok since I did it when I added the user account with a shell script. What I want is a section in smb.conf that automatically generates samba share path for every user. Like [homes], it represents say, //10.0.0.1/jake, //10.0.0.1/fiona. One section for all

Comment: I'm thinking of just creating a [home2] section. All users can see home2 and once they connect to home2 they can see their own directory there. Not consistent when they access their home directory but acceptable.